# postgresql jsonb array query using gin index

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Using postgresql 10.6. I have a table called **place** with a jsonb field of **cities** which holds a json array. I created a **gin** index on cities. cities json array will have tens of thousands of records. I need to query this array for 5000 city name in the where clause. The query is absolutely supposed to use gin index for performance. My sample query in below fiddle is not using the index as far as I saw in the execution plan. How this query should be written to use the index so it runs quickly.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE place (       
    cities jsonb NULL   
);

CREATE INDEX "IX_place_cities" ON place USING gin (cities);

INSERT INTO place
(cities)
VALUES('[{"name": "paris", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "london", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "berlin", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "istanbul", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "prag", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "rome", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "wien", "continent": "europe"},
{"name": "tokyo", "continent": "asia"},
{"name": "beijing", "continent": "asia"},
{"name": "dakar", "continent": "africa"},
{"name": "daresselam", "continent": "africa"},
{"name": "kuala lumpur", "continent": "asia"},
{"name": "barcelona", "continent": "europe"}]');
```

My query:

```
select elems.arrayitem
FROM (
  select jsonb_array_elements(place.cities) as arrayitem 
  from place
) as elems
where elems.arrayitem @> '{"name": "paris"}' 
   or elems.arrayitem @> '{"name": "dakar"}'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d28fd/3)

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: The problem is probably earlier. 1) normalize the data model 2) Where do these 5000 city names come from? You should rather join the table with that source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you unnest the JSON, you can't use an index anymore. I think you are looking for:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(p.cities) item
from place p
where p.cities @> '[{"name": "paris"}]'
   or p.cities @> '[{"name": "dakar"}]'
```

Or more explicitly:

```
select e.item
from place p
   cross join jsonb_array_elements(p.cities) as e(item)
where p.cities @> '[{"name": "paris"}]'
   or p.cities @> '[{"name": "dakar"}]'
```

The GIN index will only be used if you a lot of rows in the table (**not** elements in the array!) and your WHERE condition reduces the many rows to just some.

If you store everything in one giant JSON value in a single row, no index will improve your query. You should normalize your data model instead - which seems quite easy to do as you don't seem to have any dynamic structure and all elements share the same keys (=column).

Comment: Just modified the schema according to your suggestion. No more giant JSON!
Used your first query, but no need to unnest any json this time. However, still can't use index as far as I saw in the execution plan. What correction shold be made to use the index?

Comment: @killjoy: for a small table like that, Postgres will never use an index. An index is helpful if the WHERE condition can reduce the result from many rows to just a few. You will need to have at least a several thousand rows and select only very few to see an index improve your query. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120036/). You should seriously consider normalizing your data model

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. I had changed my data model according to your suggestion to avoid a giant json and put each json object in a separate row as shown in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/864508/2. Is there any further normalization in my data model that you may suggest?

Comment: @killjoy: `create table cities (name text, continent text);`